# Selecting max and min values in specified range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a task to parse logs table and select min and max values, then group them by dates.
So it will be like this:

1. 2022-10-20: first entry: 6:30, last entry: 16:25
2. 2022-10-19: first entry: 6:28, last entry: 15:35

I could just group by `date("date")` and find `min(date), max(date)` like this:

```
select 
        replace(date("date")::varchar, '-', '') "date",
        min("date"),
        max("date")
    FROM request_logs
    WHERE user_id = N
      AND date BETWEEN 'X' AND 'Y'
    GROUP BY date("date")`);
```

, but this does not satisfies these two requirements:

- first entry should be selected only if its hour value is between 6:00 and 18:00
- last entry should be selected only if its hour value is between 18:00 and 6:00

I can't understand, what exactly should I use to build a nice query for this task.
And what is also difficult is that last entry can be on the next day, before 6:00..

Comment: Why dont you add your requirements in the where? I mean: AND date::time BETWEEEN x2 and y2

Comment: @user_0 but this will only satisfy either first or second requirement, not both at the same time?

Comment: You are right. I can think, you can use a union and 2 separate queries..

Comment: Can you share a sample of the input table and the expected output

Comment: What is the actual data type for `"date"`? If it is, as I suspect, a `timestamp` why call it `"date"` in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make two separate queries, like user_0 said, but make another to take actual min and max date values.
It is little bit weird, but does the job.